# Dell Server Raid 1 drive quick replacement with 2 exact copies

Tags: sql-server-2014, windows-server, hardware, raid

Apologies if I am posting this to the wrong place.

We are unfortunately having to handle our own server administration in-house and no one here is an expert at servers in any way! (we are web app developers and .Net/SQL/javascript programmers)

We have a Dell server with a RAID 1 setup on the C: drive (for the Windows Server system) and D: drives (for our SQL databases), which has worked great in the past when 1 of the 2 drives has an issue..

We recently had the C drive fail completely, (BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO) and unfortunately the RAID 1 did not help in this case as the system on both active drives were completely unusable (at least to our knowledge).

We are back up and running now but it is very time consuming to have to re-install Windows Server, SQL Server and all the updates.

My question : Is there an alternative way we could be setting up or backing up the C: drive to avoid having to reinstall everything from scratch, should we have another such failure?

Comment: Having a RAID-1 volume is not in any way an alternative to making regular OS _and_ SQL Server backups; it sounds like you didn't have backups (since you had to reinstall stuff), so you should start making them.

Comment: You need more than one server. More than just storage can go bad.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an alternative way we could be setting up or backing up the C: drive to avoid having to reinstall everything from scratch, should we have another such failure?

Yes.  You can backup Windows Server.  But you should really be using Hyper-V, which has all sorts of time-saving capabilities, like VM backup, VM migration, and the ability to cleanly share host hardware resources between VMs.